# How do I edit my very-old-questions without pushing it onto the "active" feed?

Tags: discussion, support

I was just going through some old posts of mine. Thought I could improve them just a tiny bit. I have no intention of bringing them back onto the "active questions" feed. How do I edit them, yet keep them away from the feed?

Comment: It's not possible. Just edit them; it's not a big deal unless you do ten at a time or something like that. People who don't want to see bumped old questions can use the "new questions" filter.

Comment: Here are some relevant Meta SE Posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page?rq=1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246774/review-queue-to-approve-edits-to-very-old-posts-with-without-bumping

Comment: @sumelic thank you for sharing. It appears, I've no choice but to refrain from making those minor edits.

Comment: If you edit the occasional one who's even going to notice? It's when someone edits/re-tags twenty posts at a time that it becomes slightly annoying. Who knows, the question and its answers may come as a pleasant surprise to those who didn't see it the first time round.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @sumelic notes in comments and via the offered link, there is no way to edit any post without bumping it to the *active questions* feed.

I understand SE's philosophy on the matter to be that improvements to posts are encouraged because the site is intended to be a repository of expertly answered questions. The community goes to great lengths to review, edit, vote and cull questions and answers for quality. So if you can raise the quality of an old post, it would be consistent with Stack Exchange's philosophy for you to do so.

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date.
>   [- help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/editing)